# What does the vector space $\mathbb{Q}[z]/\mathbb{Q}[z]·P(z)$ of the polynomials modulo the multiples of $P(z)$ represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

I only wish to understand a sentence which is unclear to me. It's the following:

*Let $P(z) = z^2 − z − 56 \in \mathbb{Q}[z]$, $V$ be the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{Q}[z]/\mathbb{Q}[z]·P(z)$ of the polynomials modulo the multiples of $P(z)$.*

What does the space $V$ actually represents? For instance, how can we find the images of very elmentary polynomials like $1$ or $z$ in $V$? I am confused with the quotient multiplied by multiples of $P(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that $P(z)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[z]$, because it is of degree $2$ and does not have a root in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then it is also irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[z]$, so the ideal generated by it is a maximal ideal. If we consider a root $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ of $P$, we can look at the evaluation homomorphism $ev_\alpha:\mathbb{Q}[z]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, that takes a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[z]$ and evaluates it at $z=\alpha$. Since $\alpha$ is a root of $P$, we have that the ideal generated by $P$ is in the kernel, hence we have equality since the ideal generated by $P$ is maximal. Then the isomorphism theorem gives us $$\mathbb{Q}[z]/(P)=\mathbb{Q}[z]/\operatorname{ker}(ev_{\alpha})\cong \operatorname{im}(ev_\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}[a]\subseteq\mathbb{C}.$$ In conclusion, we can view this quiotent as adjoining a root of $P$ to $\mathbb{Q}$; this space has dimension $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. We can see this using the uniqueness of the division with remainder in $\mathbb{Q}[z]$. A $\mathbb{Q}$-basis is then seen to be $1,z$ (the element $z^2$gets identified with $z+56$ in the quotient), and via $ev_\alpha$ we see that a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is given by $1,\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you that's very useful! The only thing I'm not sure to catch is the identification of z^2 with z +56 you mentioned, could you elaborate on this result?

Comment: A residue cass in the quotient $g+(P)$ is equal to another one, say $f+(P)$, if therir difference lies in the ideal generated by (P), so in particular $z^2$ and $z+56$ give rise to the same residue class, because there difference is $z^2-z-56$, so it is actually $P$.

Comment: Ah yes I understand thanks !

Comment: With this basis how could I then express the multiplication by z?

Comment: By division with remainder, we can write every polynomial in $g\in \mathbb{Q}[z]$ uniqely as $g=q\cdot P+r$, where $r$ has degree strictly less than $P$, so strictly less than $2$. We apply the residue map $\mathbb{Q}[z]\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[z]/(P)$, that is, we mod out $P$, we get $g+(P)=q\cdot P+r +(P)=r+(P)$. So we can write every residue class as $r+(P)$, where $r=a_0\cdot 1+a_1\cdot z\in\operatorname{span}_\mathbb{Q}(1,z),$ for $a_0,a_1\in\mathbb{Q}$ giving that $1,z$ span $\mathbb{Q}[z]/(P)$ - or rather their residue classes - and they are also linearly independent, so a basis.

Comment: Thanks again, but there is one step I don't follow: when you write "$q\times P + r + (P) = r + (P)$". Is it because "$q\times P \in (P)"?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Okey thank you!